# Element removal in image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

Python 3, cv2 library (not a must)
Trying to remove the name tag "roadhog" from this image (and leave the outline of the character as is):
[image]

(I cannot edit it manually, I got over 50K images like this one, but all look similar- outline and text)

Comment: *"thank you, but from your answer i saw that i wasnt clear on the term "same": all the images i have consist of an outline and a name (can be in different areas of the image)"*  Maybe you could show some other examples? Does the text colour or size change maybe?

Comment: So some are JPEG's on a black background and some are PNGs on a transparent background? Does the text rotate? Change size? Change font? Change colour?

Comment: I can change the background to be whatever is needed. text does not rotate, does not change size significantly (the blurriness might differ from one image to another- but they were all taken using the same prespective), no font change, no color change (except from the blurriness u can see in these images)

Comment: What is the question? All you’re saying is what you are trying to do. What have you tried, what is the difficulty? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use erosion image (as marker) and morphological reconstruction.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('in.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
marker = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)
while True:
    tmp=marker.copy()
    marker=cv2.dilate(marker, kernel2)
    marker=cv2.min(thresh, marker)
    difference = cv2.subtract(marker, tmp)
    if cv2.countNonZero(difference) == 0:
        break

mask=cv2.bitwise_not(marker)
mask_color = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
out=cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask_color)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)
cv2.imshow('result', out )
```

See result:[image]